# make qt distribution neat. remove part of dll?

Tags: windows, qt, dll

I made a qt program on windows. 
And I want to share with my friend.
but my friend use pure windows 7.

it would be nice if I can include only dll needed.
and it would be much nicer if I can remove part of dll which are unused.
(to reduce size of dll)

how can I do this? thanks

Comment: could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to decrease the size of the actual DLLs in any way implies removing code, which is a very bad idea. You can still change the Qt source if you either:

- have a commercial license
- share all the changes made

...that being said, this is not the way to go in your particular case.

Trying to decrease the number of needed DLLs is a whole different story - your application will typically require only the DLLs of the modules that it needs. But some modules have dependencies to other modules, so you might end up getting DLLs for stuff that you yourself don't use but is used somewhere internally. For example, you might end up with a dependency on a Direct3D DLL for a `QWidget` based project, which is due to the fact many of the stock Qt builds are built to use ANGLE which is a DirectX based emulation layer of OpenGL (ES) 2. You can use a Qt build for desktop OpenGL to remove a few DLLs, but they are fairly small compared to the Qt DLLs. Omitting the webkit from Qt is a good way to remove a few MB of DLL dependencies.

The last option has already been mentioned by peppe - static linking, which requires you to make a static build of Qt itself. And there are some limitations - you must have a commercial Qt license for that particular platform if you want to distribute a closed source/commercial application. For open source stuff and testing purposes I guess it is ok. Static builds are really nice because they offer better performance and you end up with a single file of about 8-9 MB for basic GUI application (QtCore/QtGUI and QtWidgets). Last time I checked, QtQuick/QML applications didn't work with a static build.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using a static, release build of Qt, with Link Time Optimizations enabled. You need MSVC for this (no idea if it works with MinGW's GCC), and configure Qt with

```
configure -static -release -ltcg
```

Of course, be also aware of what static linking implies when using a (L)GPL version of Qt.

---

In general you can trim out parts of Qt by means of feature switches. The Unix configure script directly supports that by passing `-no-feature-featurename` where `featurename` is one of the features listed in the `src/corelib/global/qfeatures.txt` file.

Probably there's a way of doing using the Windows configure executable (eventually, add the corresponding `QT_NO_FEATURE` macro to the generated `src/corelib/global/qconfig.h` file...).

Be aware that feature switches are not officially supported ("best effort" support), so disabling some pieces of Qt might break your build. YMMV.